# ePub Reader in Firefox

Tags: firefox-extensions, epub

Sorry if am being stupid, it just caught my eyes and was wondering what story could be behind it.
I just installed ePub Reader add-on to Firefox 7 and when I opened an ePub file, the url shows:

`chrome://epubreader/content/reader.xul?id=1.`

Why is `chrome:` being shown there?

Answer (score 1):

The `chrome:` protocol is generally used for browser chrome in Firefox (meaning the browser's user interface as opposed to "content" - the web pages loaded into the browser). You can find some information on it in the [XUL Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL). This terminology is much older than Google Chrome that seems to be the source of your confusion.

Comment: Yes, the name Google "Chrome" confused me. I shall go through the link. Thank you for your time and effort.